# How written array long

Tags: arrays

How written array long? i want written this

[image]

but i get this:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
    \[
        a=hardlim(Wp_1 +b)= hardlim ([\begin{array}{ccc}0.5& -1 & –0.5
         \end{array}] [\begin{array}{ccc}-1\\1\\-1 \end{array}]+0.5 )
        \]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

[image]

i wonder why you load of the `amsmath` package and than not use its math environments? for example `bmatrix` add `[` and `]` which are automatically scaled to matrix size. using array you need to to this manually. in your case instead

```
[\begin{array}{ccc}-1\\1\\-1 \end{array}]
```

you should write

```
\left[\begin{array}{ccc}-1\\1\\-1 \end{array}\right]
```

using `bmatrix` your code become shorter and more clear:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\[
a = \text{hardlim}(\mathbf{Wp}_1 +b)
  = \text{hardlim} \left(\begin{bmatrix}0.5 & -1 & –0.5\end{bmatrix}
                         \begin{bmatrix}-1\\1\\-1 \end{bmatrix}+0.5 \right)
\]
\end{document}
```

the `hardlim` seems to be new math operator. in this case it should be defined as:

```
\DeclareMathOperator{\hardlim}{hardlim}
```

and than used as `\hardlim` (see new example below) and not as collection of variables *h, a, r, d, l* and *m*.

**edit**
(regarding comment of [Dũng Vũ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/156344/d%C5%A9ng-v%C5%A9)): the align cells contents in matrices can be changed by workaround provided in [matrix with vertical and horizontal lines](http://texblog.net/latex-archive/maths/amsmath-matrix%20with%20vertical%20and%20horizontal%20lines).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\makeatletter   % extend of asmath matrix features
\renewcommand*\env@matrix[1][*\c@MaxMatrixCols c]{%
\hskip -\arraycolsep
\let\@ifnextchar\new@ifnextchar
\array{#1}}
\makeatother

\DeclareMathOperator{\hardlim}{hardlim} % new math operator

\begin{document}
\[
a = \hardlim(\mathbf{Wp}_1 +b)
  = \hardlim \left(\begin{bmatrix}0.5 & -1 & –0.5\end{bmatrix}
                   \begin{bmatrix}[r]-1\\1\\-1 \end{bmatrix}+0.5 \right)
\]
\end{document}
```

which gives:

[image]

Comment: +1 for nice alignment in code. However, I think the only thing left is to align the `-1  1  -1` in the vertical array.

Comment: @DũngVũ, see edited answer. is now as you liked that be matrix content aligned?

Comment: Yes, it is perfect now (in my opinion, at least)